# Function to get another varaible value using index number in R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I would like to ask your help how to get variable value from the other data frame located inside list by using the index number.

I have 2 lists in R that each contains 20000 thousand of data frames.

First list, let's call it as a list A :
View(A) contains :

1 (data frame) [10x1]

2 (data frame) [200x1]

3 (data frame) [80x1]

...

20000 (data frame) [1000x1]

Let's zoom for data frame (1) :

| Row Number | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | paris |
| 2 | london |
| 3 | jakarta |
| 4 | mumbai |
| 5 | manchester |
| 6 | hanoi |
| 7 | sydney |
| 8 | new york |
| 9 | milan |
| 10 | seoul |

Please note that the "Row Number is not a column", but the row names for each row (it doesn't exist actually). I just want to make the a clear concept.

Then, this is my second list called B :
View(A) contains :

1 (data frame) [3x3]

2 (data frame) [77x5]

3 (data frame) [5x6]

...

20000 (data frame) [888x1]

The name of data frames are the same for both lists (A and B) but different number of columns.
The data frame in list A contains only one column (ID) but the data frame in list B can be containing several columns.

Let's take a look for the data frame 1 in B

| in_1 | in_2 | in_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | NA |
| 8 | NA | NA |
| 9 | 5 | NA |

The values located in each data frame from list B are the index number from the list A.
The goal is by using these values, I need to get the ID's values from each same name data frame (ex: data frame 888 from list B can only be matched with data frame 888 from list A) from the list A.

Here's the desired result by retaking our example from data frame 1 :

| in_1 | in_2 | in_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| paris | jakarta | NA |
| new york | NA | NA |
| milan | manchester | NA |

I can make this result by using imbricated loops which taking so much time, knowing that I have 20000 data frames in each list, it will be take so much time to iterate each element, row and column.

Could you help me to solve this problem ? Especially to reduce the execution time ?

I thank you in advance.

## Edit :

Following the solution provided by langtang, I received an error message :

"Error in as.matrix(x)[i] : subscript out of bounds"

Therefore, I would like to provide the situation more in detail :

The are 2 lists, each list contains 19000 data frames.

For the list called list "A", all data frames contain 3 columns. But all data frames can have different row numbers.

Here's the elements for list "A" :

[00001] list[3x3] (S3: data.frame)

[00002] list[10x3] (S3: data.frame)

...

[19000] list[27x3] (S3: data.frame)

Zoom for A[[00001]] :

[image: Zoom for A[[00001]] :]

Then for the second list called B have the same number of data frames but the number of columns and rows varied.

Here's the elements for list "A" :

[00001] list[2x3] (S3: data.frame)

[00002] list[3x10] (S3: data.frame)

...

[19000] list[77x88] (S3: data.frame)

Zoom for B[[00001]] :
[image: Zoom for B[[00001]] :]

Note that the suffix "X" for the column name depends on the number of columns exist on each data frame. For example here, the data framme A[[00001]] has only 3 columns, therefore the suffix "X" goes until "3".

The values exist in this data frame are the index number for the same name data frame in list "A".

Here's what I want as a result :

[image: The expected result]

The index number are replaced with the id's value.

By using the index number, I want to get the values from column "id" from the data frame located in list "A".

Please note that the number of columns in the data frames in the second list does not depend on the number of columns in the data frames in the first list.

Have you any solution for this problem ? Knowing that the solution given by lanngtang gave me an error message ""Error in as.matrix(x)[i] : subscript out of bounds".

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, but I think this does what you want?

```r
myfun <- function(df1, df2) {
   data.frame(in_1 = df1$ID[df2$in_1], in_2 = df1$ID[df2$in_2], 
              in_3 = df2$in_3)
}
Map(myfun, A, B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
f <- \(a,b) {
  d = dim(b)
  setNames(data.frame(matrix(a[as.matrix(b)],nrow = d[1], ncol=d[2])), names(b))
} 

# using Map -- thanks Ben Bolker
# update - if A and B are named lists, but the list are not in the same order, you can index `A` by the names of `B`

Map(f,A[names(B)],B)
```

Output:

```
$d1
      in_1       in_2 in_3
1    paris    jakarta <NA>
2 new york       <NA> <NA>
3    milan manchester <NA>

$d2
  in_1 in_2 in_3   in_4
1  cat  dog fish   <NA>
2 frog <NA>  pig    rat
3 bird  cow <NA> monkey
```

Input:

```
A = list(d1 = structure(list(ID = c("paris", "london", "jakarta", 
"mumbai", "manchester", "hanoi", "sydney", "new york", "milan", 
"seoul")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L)), d2 = structure(list(
    ID = c("cat", "fish", "dog", "horse", "cow", "pig", "goose", 
    "frog", "bird", "rat", "monkey")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L)))

B = list(d1 = structure(list(in_1 = c(1, 8, 9), in_2 = c(3, NA, 5
), in_3 = c(NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), d2 = structure(list(in_1 = c(1, 8, 9), in_2 = c(3, NA, 
5), in_3 = c(2, 6, NA), in_4 = c(NA, 10, 11)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)))
```

#### Update: solution also works on the updated data:

```
A = list("00001" = data.frame(id = c(7722, 8756,6533), city=c("Paris","Jakarta", "New York"),country = c("France", "Indonesia", "US")))
B = list("00001" = data.frame(X1 = c(2,1,3), X2 = c(3, NA, 1), X3 = c(NA, NA, 2)))

f <- \(a,b) {
  d = dim(b)
  setNames(data.frame(matrix(a["id"][as.matrix(b)],nrow = d[1], ncol=d[2])), names(b))
} 

n = intersect(names(A), names(B))
Map(f,A[n], B[n])
```

Output:

```
$`00001`
    X1   X2   X3
1 8756 6533   NA
2 7722   NA   NA
3 6533 7722 8756
```

Comment: By the way I have an error message below :

Error in as.matrix(x)[i] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: What should I need to do to solve this error ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: the code above runs on the input I provided, and the input you provided. You'll need to provide a richer example for us to better understand your problem

Comment: Well, I have 19000 data frames in list A and 19000 in list B. 
The data frame named 'A' located in list B correspond withe the data frame names 'A' in list 'A' and containing several index number from data frame 'A' in list 'A'. The goal is if the name of data frame from both list are same, then I do the operation to extract the informations from the list 'A' by using the index number from data frame 'A' coming from list 'B'. I hope it is clear for you ?

Comment: are they in order? is the nth frame from A matched with the nth frame from B?  If they are not, in the same order, there is a way around it, but my solution assumes they are in the same order (that is, frame 1 from A matches to frame 1 from B, frame 2 from A matches to frame 2 in B)

Comment: The are not in order unfortunately. Do you think that's the problem ? 
Because the number of observations for each data frames are differents

Comment: if they are not in the same order, you can do something like this in the final line: `Map(f,A[names(B)],B)`.  This forces the list in A to be in the same order as the list in B

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work... It gives me the same error message. 
Does the number of different lines / columns  between the two data frames affect the operation?

Comment: do all frames in B match with 1 and only 1 frame in A?

Comment: I'm trying to help here, but you really need to provide a dataset that demonstrates that my solution doesn't work.

Comment: Do I need to create a new question to provide the dataset ?

Comment: not necessarily, if you have a example where my code doesn't work, use that example in the original question.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll try to visualize the problem as soon as possible.

Comment: Note langtang, I have added some precisions. I hope you understand what I'm struggling with. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: again, my code works on your new data. I cannot stress enough how important it is for you to provide some data for which my code fails.

Comment: Langtang, I'm really sorry because it's because of confidential data.  I could not give you the original data but on the other hand I built data with the same model.  So the data in which you applied your new function.  I sincerely thank you.

Comment: you should be able to find out which one(s) of your pairs is failing.,, use a for loop, and print the name each time, until it fails: `n=intersect(names(B), names(A); for(nm in n) {print(nm); f(A[[n]], B[[n]])}`  Then examine that failing pair, and see why it is failing.  The code does work on the example data you provide.

Comment: I have re-executed your codes but I have the same error message. I have an error on data frame '00008' but I really don't know what's wrong with this data frame that located in list B.